# Can std::string be used for openssl crypto keys?

Tags: c++, c++11, openssl

Is it safe to use `std::string` for the keys when using openssl?

I am currently using `std::vector<uint8_t>` for managing keys for use with the openssl API because I am not sure how `std::string` deals with the non-printable chars.

Comment: Yes, it can, but you usually want to use a zero-ing allocator. And a [SGI `Rope<T, A>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) might even be a better choice because it provides concatenation; but does not have the character trait overhead.

Answer (score 1):

fortunately for you, aside some stuff like short string optimizations, there aren't many differences between `std::vector<char>` and `std::string`.

`std::string` doesn't really care what it holds even if the characters inside are not valid ASCII/UTF8 characters/sequences.

this is one of the bad things in `std::basic_string`, unfortunately for the rest of cases.

Comment: The biggest difference I've found is `std::string` can always be copied and returned, while a `std::vector` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` doesn't know anything about printable/unprintable chars aswell as about encodings. As example,

```
std::string str;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    str.push_back('\0');
}
```

is a perfectly valid string.

But there can be an issue with security. You need to guarantee that all memory with crypto keys should be filled with something (zeroes maybe) when it's being freed.